# I need To Set Font from .ttf File

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm Trying to set font to my system and use it in my application it works fine for android but it does not apply for IOS
- First I Added .ttf File to Resources in IOS Project

[image]

Then Added This Font to Entitlements.plist

[image]

For Android, I Added to Assets Folder

[image]

Then App File in the Main Application I added this Code in dictionary Resources

```
 <Style x:Key="LableStyle" TargetType="Label" >
        <Setter Property="Label.FontFamily">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                    <OnPlatform.Android>
                        DroidSansArabic.ttf#DroidSansArabic
                            </OnPlatform.Android>
                    <OnPlatform.iOS>
                        DroidSansArabic
                    </OnPlatform.iOS>
                </OnPlatform>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And for The Label I Added the Style like this

```
<Label HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" 
   Margin="20,5,0,0"
   x:Name="lblForgotPassword"
   Text="Forgot Password"
   Style="{StaticResource LableStyle}">
</Label>
```

But it works fine in Android but not working in IOS Why ?

Comment: You don't need to add it to the entitlements.plist but the info.plist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would assume your font family name is incorrect on iOS. The macOS/iOS font names are not the filename sans extension, the names are defined within the `ttf` itself.

The `DroidSansArabic.ttf` on my macOS and the one that I have used on iOS uses the family name of **`B Tabassom`**

So the usage of it in Forms would be:

```
label.FontFamily = Device.OnPlatform(
    iOS: "B Tabassom",
    Android: "DroidSansArabic.ttf#DroidSansArabic",
    WinPhone: null
);
```

As there are a number of DroidSansArabic.ttf floating around, verify what your font family name is by opening the `ttf` in macOS's Font Book and looking at the title bar:

[image]

If your macOS has it already installed, look in the name column:

[image]

**Update:** You also the `UIAppFonts` key in the wrong `.plist`, it goes in the `Info.plist`:

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
                <string>DroidSansArabic.ttf</string>
        </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks so much I will check and let you Know

Comment: I Installed the font the font name was Droid Sans Arabic Regular
But also the Same problem

Comment: @VictorFaltas is the name the title bar: `Droid Sans Arabic Regular` or `Droid Sans Arabic`? i.e. Do not include the `Regular` part, only the name that is in the Title bar for uninstalled fonts or the font name column if installed.

Comment: Also tried without regular but not working I think there is another reason

Comment: @VictorFaltas You also the UIAppFonts key in the wrong .plist, it goes in the Info.plist.... I added that to my answer...

Comment: Thanks, It Works Now there is a bug in Visual Studio I Think once I save the data in info.plist It's changed and reverted back automatically after save.
But now i added
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
                <string>DroidSansArabic.ttf</string>
        </array>
As XML so It's working now Fine Really Thanks